# 404 when using PWA version of Angular App

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have an angular app that I host with GitHub pages. It works fine, but I recently turned it into a Progressive Web App. When I try and open it as a PWA on my phone, I get a 404 error. I think I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. When I build my app, it creates the wrong file paths in the index.html file.

The code should be:

```html
    <script src="./dist/runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js" type="module"></script>
```

But instead, its:

```html
    <script src="runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js" type="module"></script>
```

How can I get the correct filepath specified when I build the app? What file do I need to specify this?

Answer (score 0):

While ng-build you can specify basehref path so that your root path can works

```
ng build --prod --base-href /<project_name>/
```

Example:

```
ng build --prod --base-href http://www.example.com
```

Comment: This is the command I run when I build it: ng build --prod --base-href "https://m0kova01.github.io/DiscGolfProject/"

Comment: this is are you trying ? i can see this link is working.

Comment: Yes, the app works when it is running normally. But if I try and use it as a PWA, it comes back with a 404 error. Try running a lighthouse audit on it to see what I mean

Comment: if possible can you give PWA app link if it there ?

Comment: the link is https://m0kova01.github.io/DiscGolfProject/home. It should already be a pwa app. If I go to firefox on my phone, it prompts me to add it to my home screen. But when I open it, a 404 error shows up